# jquery Pageinit called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery Development. I am creating a single Page Application. I am calling a pageinit method when navigate from one page to another page. When i navigate from and back between the two screens i see the page init is called multiple times.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", '#docPage', function(event) {
               home.doc.init();
               });
```

And even while navigating back i am calling unbind event also.

```
 $('#BackButton').on('tap', function(event) {
                       event.preventDefault();

                       $.mobile.changePage("homepage.html", {
                                           transition: "fade",
                                           reverse: false,
                                           changeHash: false
                                           });
                       teardown();
                       });
};

teardown(){

home.doc.unbindEvents();
}
```

Can any one guide me the best practice of navigating in a single Page application. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why is this tagged as ios?

Comment: I am developing this application for iPad . i want to know is there any standards followed if the app is developed for iOS platform

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile and [its pageinit event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)?

Comment: yes i am using jQuery Mobile Pageinit method

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to `pageinit` listener being assigned more than once - check that it is not being re-added each time you 'navigate' to a different page.

Your unbinding could not be working as expected.  Try and change the anonymous function  `$(document).on("pageinit", '#docPage', function(event) {
               home.doc.init();
               })`

to a named function declared previously in the code.  This could provide some insight.